# Are handprints or art made by impressions also prohibited?

Tags: halal-haram, art

Assalamu alaykum. As an example, if someone put their face in clay and effectively made a sculpture of a face with his imprint, is that haram to do on purpose? Please provide hadith or other references if you can inshaAllah.